# Why is the for loop not working properly for larger datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

This is the small 10 record dataset that I tried my code on
[image]
And this is what it's supposed to look like (the LOST PACKETS attribute):
[image]

This is the code that I wrote where the anomaly shows up:

```
for lost_p, plr in zip(df['LOST PACKETS'], df['PACKET LOSS RATIO']):
    if (lost_p == 0):
        df['LOST PACKETS'] = df['LOST PACKETS'].replace(lost_p, 0)
    elif (lost_p > 0 and plr > 0.07):
        df['LOST PACKETS'] = df['LOST PACKETS'].replace(lost_p, 1)
    elif (lost_p > 0 and plr < 0.07):
        df['LOST PACKETS'] = df['LOST PACKETS'].replace(lost_p, 0)
    else:
        df['LOST PACKETS'] = df['LOST PACKETS'].replace(lost_p, 1)
```

df

This is the dataset I've been trying to work on:
[image]
And this is the result of the code (where it's clear that it shows 0 in places where it should show 1):
[image]

Might I add that when `df['LOST PACKETS'].value_counts()` is executed, it shows:

```
0    14760
Name: LOST PACKETS, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df[['LOST PACKETS','PACKET LOSS RATIO']].head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `.replace` across the whole column on *every* loop iteration.

In `pandas`, operations like these are usually done through indexing, e.g.:

```py
selection = (df['LOST PACKETS'] > 0) & (df['PACKET LOSS RATIO'] > 0.07)
df.loc[selection, 'LOST PACKETS'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your condition logic is wrong. You overwrite LOST PACKETS data each time. Probably, last condition block is equal to replace 0 .

Solution:
You need to select indexes replace; for example for second if df[(df["LOST PACKETS"] > 0 ) and (df[df['PACKET LOSS RATIO']] > 0.07)].index then chage this index lost packet values.